# Language pair lists

Tags: usability, interface, bootstrap

I need to implement UI for language pair selection in Chrome extension. The simplest solution is 2 comboboxes with language list (variant 1).

But i think it takes too long to open a combobox, find needed language, click on it. So i think of a language toolbar of some sort, so a user can place on it several languages which he frequently uses.

Is it a better solution than the first one?

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fh4zfG.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

P. S. i've just visited Google Translate page.. and they've already done something similar:-) But the list is created automatically

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go with the second one. It looks a lot like Google Translate.

The great thing about it is that it's smart. It remembers what languages you've used before, since there's a good chance you might want to use the combination of these two languages again.

Users have to think less and the task gets completed faster. Win-win.